# Is there any way to send a REST request when application is deleted from a certain device?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

#### Intro

I developed an app using ionic 5 that saves a user UUID and basically his device UUID is his "username",
on the first startup, I also generate a unique "password" and saves it in NativeStorage (local storage).

Everything he does on this app is now associated with his UUID.

#### The problem:

When a user deleted this app, I need to send a REST request and delete all of its data in my SQL SERVER Database. (including his UUID & UNIQUE PASSWORD).

#### What I have tried

Yes, I know when it's his first startup so I know to delete device data if exists,
but a user can see on my website "all of the connected devices".

#### Problem & Goal Example

- Mike downloads "MyApp"
- Mike see on my website "iPhone X is connected"
- Mike restore his phone and sell it to Joe
- **Problem 1**: Mike still see on my website that "iPhone X is connected" and might be stressed about it even though, no one can use his old phone.. why? (next step)
- Joe downloads "MyApp", the app recognizes it's his first use and delete the device -> adding this as a new & clean one
- Mike now won't see on my website "iPhone X is connected".
- **Problem 2**: If joe will never download my app, mike will keep seeing this and might be stressed his information leaks.

#### Question & extra:

1. Is there any way to recognize when an app is no longer installed on a certain device?
2. Is there a way to get a list of all devices that currently have my app installed?
3. You have any idea to handle this situation if 1\2 is not possible?
   To clarify, I need a solution for both IOS & Android

Comment: 1. No, there is no notification when an app is removed. 2. There is no way to get a list of devices that have your app installed. 3. There is also no way to identify devices (at least on iOS) across device resets; there is no way you can know that Joe is using the phone that Mike used to use. Mike will still see "iPhone X Connected" regardless of whether Joe installs the app because as far as you know they are different devices. You should provide a method for users to remove their old devices manually if that is a concern

Comment: Well, first of all thanks, second, I will implement a way to remove a device manually, but your comment about “different” devices is not quite true. If I deleted the app, restored my device and sold it to Joe, Joe is not the same UUID as I Was. So next time he’ll install the app, I’ll recognize his first time, and will send a “clean” to delete it and create it as a new one

Comment: A "clean to delete" what?  Yes, you will identify that this is the first time Joe is running the app, but you have no information on what other users may have previously used this device since there is no unique *device* identifier available to you.

Comment: Device UUID is available to me when you first open the app, with this I go to my DB and check whether or not this UUID is there...

Comment: But that will be a different UUID after a device reset. (at least on iOS, I would presume also on Android, but maybe they still haven't fixed all of their privacy issues yet). On iOS you do not have access to a device identifier that lives beyond device reset

Comment: OH, this I did not now. Thank you for the information, I will implement a delete device button.